# Register an exe to custom protocol handler using packaging project

Tags: uwp, registry, win-universal-app, launch, desktop-bridge

I am trying to register an exe to a custom protocol using a packaging project. I have added the following code in appxmanifest of packaging project.

```
<Extensions>
 <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol" Executable="Assets\app.exe">
   <uap:Protocol Name="app.custom.protocol" />
 </uap:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

But I am unable to launch the exe from uwp app using launchUriAsync method. It just shows the dialog asking for an app to open the protocol.

Comment: Can you share the entire appxmanifest file? Is "app.exe" a different executable than what is being used on the <Application> object?

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT yes app.exe is a different executable. I want to launch that executable from uwp app using app.custom.protocol

Comment: One more clarifying question: do you only need to launch it from the UWP app in this package, or from any app on the system? If it's only for this app, using the FullTrustProcessLauncher API would be the better choice than protocol launch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher

Comment: I will try using that API. I have one question with this protocol launch approach. When we define the custom protocol along with the executable path, it should create a corresponding entry in registry, right?

Comment: Declaring a custom protocol won't write to the registry, it will write to the state repository (modern replacement of registry), but this is really an implementation detail. Your problem is that you are not declaring it correctly. I can explain how to do it correctly, but first I am trying to determine what you really want to do.

Comment: I would really like to know how to launch the exe from uwp app using protocol approach correctly. I want to know what I missing why declaring custom protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register a custom protocol for an EXE in your package it needs to be declared as  in your appxmanifest. Note that you can have multiple  elements in your package. So for example if your main app is a UWP and you also have a Win32 executable (WPF) that you want to register as custom protocol handler you would have to author the package manifest like the below. Note that setting AppListEntry=None will prevent the Win32 EXE from showing up in the start menu.

```
<Applications>
 <Application Id="UWP" Executable="Uwp.exe" EntryPoint="Uwp.App">
  <uap:VisualElements … />
 </Application>
 <Application Id="WPF" Executable="WpfApp2\WpfApp2.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
  <uap:VisualElements AppListEntry="none" … />
  <Extensions>
   <uap3:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
    <uap3:Protocol Name="app.custom.protocol" />
   </uap3:Extension>
  </Extensions>
 </Application>
</Applications>
```

However, if all you want to do is launch your Win32 EXE from your UWP you will be better off using the FullTrustProcessLauncher API, instead of doing protocol launch:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher